Is there a tool like exiftool but written in Python?
Is there a product like exiftool but written in Python?
I would like to be able to read and write the so-called 'Details' for files that appear as headings in Windows Explorer — using Python — but can't find example code. I'm referring to details such as Title, Album ID, Genre, and so on.

Better ask your question here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ And check PyExifTool https://pypi.org/project/PyExifTool/


I'm referring to details such as Title, Album ID, Genre, and so on.

That sounds like you're asking for music file tags, which is rather secondary for exiftool – even if the particular program has grown to support many file formats, Exif itself is primarily a photo tagging standard for JPEG files. So although there are Exif modules for Python, they won't necessarily work with MP3 or M4A file types.
(And similarly, though Windows Explorer abstracts away the metadata of many different file formats, they all remain different file formats; there is no universal 'Genre' field that all file types have stored in the same way.)
So in order to find something useful, you need to know which file formats you'll be working with, and start searching based on that. For example, mutagen is a good Python library for MP3 (ID3) and MP4 tagging formats, while you'd need something that handles Exif/XMP/IPTC for photos.
...unless you specifically want to use Windows Explorer as the tagging interface, in which case you could read the fields through Windows COM APIs using PyWin32, but I'm not sure if that's a read/write interface or if it's read-only. (Either way, Explorer is pretty bad at understanding audio tag formats.)

another option might be ffmpeg with -f ffmetadata which I think can be captured on stderr ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53222231/redirect-stderr-and-stdout-from-ffmpeg-to-a-file-in-python-with-subprocess )

To be precise exiftool work with image files, TIFF, RAW, etc. (not only JPEG)
